# Why is my Query wrong and the phpMyAdmin's is not?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I made a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO slider ('h1', 'h2', 'data-bg', 'data-img', 'data-url', 'status') VALUES ('Lalala', 'Lalala', 'http://localhost/mares.com.br-final/images/backgrounds/black_thumb.jpg', 'http://localhost/mares.com.br-final/images/banners/papeis_2015.png', 'http://lalala.com', 1)
```

But it's not working and phpMyAdmin says the syntax is incorrect.

So I tried adding a line through phpMyAdmin and it gave me back a query, I cleaned it, to take away some elements that I'm not inserting in my query, and tried it, and it works...

Here's the phpMyAdmin's query:

```
INSERT INTO slider (`data-img`, `data-bg`, `data-url`, `h1`, `h2`, `status`) VALUES ('images/lalal.jpg', 'images/back/lalala.jpg', 'http://lalal.com', 'Oi', 'Olá', '1')
```

Obs: I alredy tried to change `'` for ` (the symbol to add code here) int he columns names.

The querys are identical to me, so why my query is wrong and phpMyAdmin's is not?

Comment: your are using wrong quotes for column

Comment: Your first query uses quotes instead of back ticks - columns and tables must have back ticks.

Comment: **Prepared statements**.. It will save you alot of trouble in the future...

Comment: instead of single quotes use Backticks

Comment: Seems OP *observed* that he already changed the quotation.

Comment: I changed the quotation, but i was adding it the wrong way in phpMyAdmin. The problem was the quotation. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using single quotes for column which is wrong, instead of using single code for column use Backticks.

```
wrong syntax : ('h1', 'h2', 'data-bg', 'data-img', 'data-url', 'status')
right syntax : (`data-img`, `data-bg`, `data-url`, `h1`, `h2`, `status`)
```

for more refer the below link [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)